# Django Execute a def at a time value

Tags: python, django

I'm searching for a method to make a `def` to execute at a time value when I run the server... Example once per day. One solution is to use `Celery` but i don't want to use it only for a simple def... Any suggestion? I'm using windows. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Equivalent of setInterval()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697039/python-equivalent-of-setinterval)

Comment: can I use that method combined with `py manage.py runserver`?

Answer (score 0):

There are certainly several possibilities, so this is just one of many solutions:

We use Unix cron jobs or Kubernetes cron jobs for this which call:

`./manage.py <the command>`

(or call `docker exec .... manage.py <the command>`)

You should make sure that your logs go whereever you need them to monitor the cron job.

Note: there was a similar question I've answered with more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52778625/621690

Comment: But, he use windows... maybe can write a command, but with Task Scheduler...

Answer (score 0):

Look in to using the Windows Task Scheduler to run your django task via manage.py. You can schedule it once a day from here or as often as you need.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/taskschd/task-scheduler-start-page

Use the simplest solution to solve your problem until you require a more complex solution.